# htaccess merge 301 www and https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The code below redirects none-www to www and subsequently forwards to https://

how can I merge these in one so that I won't have a double redirect.

```
# Redirect non www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.nl/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Redirect non https to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OR condition to merge both rules :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

> *'ornext|OR' (or next condition) Use this to combine rule conditions with a local OR instead of the implicit AND.*

Reference : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 1):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```